# Google Sheets - Function to split a string into columns

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column containing strings of emojis with no space in between of various lengths on Sheets and I would like to split them into separate columns each containing just one emoji.

Examples:

Input

Output ||

Sheets doesn't have the split to fixed width function unlike Excel, and can't use Excel because certain emojis are rendered incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming emojis in A1, try

```
=split(regexreplace(A1, "(.)", "_$1"), "_")
```

and see if that works?

Comment: Thanks--worked like a charm albeit issues with certain emojis with gender and skin tone information. E.g.: ‍♀️ is split into three columns: ||♀|️